# Javascript operator expression

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

What does means by following expression please give any reference for expression like that in javascript

```
var variable= somevalue!== undefined;
```

Thanks
Vishal

Comment: I believe the point of your question is the meaning of the `!==` operator. That's used for explicit comparitons. You may search for [other related questions here in SO, like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!== is the exact mismatch comparator (maybe not the proper name).

basically 1 != "1" evaluates as false, but 1 !== "1" evaluates as true.

In the case above, if *somevalue* is anything other than undefined *variable* will be true.

Answer (score 1):

This is assigning the variable `variable` a boolean value based on the outcome of comparing the `someValue` variable to a value of `undefined`.

`variable` will end being either `true` or `false` depending if `someValue` is currently defined in the code.

The `!==` operator means strict does not equal, as in it doesn't equal in type or in value.

Assigning a boolean like this would be good if you need to reuse the value of the comparison. Instead of doing the comparison multiple times over in different if statements, you can assign a single variable, do the comparison once, and then use the boolean value multiple times in the code.

You can read more about JavaScript's comparison operators on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Answer (score 1):

The expression `somevalue!== undefined` will return either `true` or `false`.

The variable `variable` will then be set to that true/false value.